# zsh Spaceship theme customization

Tags: zsh

I want to change some options of my zsh shell theme [spaceship](https://denysdovhan.com/spaceship-prompt/)

I currently have the theme installed and active.
I want the theme to always show my current battery life.
See here -> https://denysdovhan.com/spaceship-prompt/docs/Options.html#battery-battery .

I put `SPACESHIP_BATTERY_SHOW = always` at the very bottom of my `~/.zshrc` file.
My problem is that now when I open iterm2 I get the error `/Users/***/.zshrc:12: command not found: SPACESHIP_BATTERY_SHOW`

Am I putting the configuration in the wrong spot?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When defining parameters in `zsh` (or any other POSIX-compliant shell) there must not be any spaces before or after `=`. So adding `SPACESHIP_BATTERY_SHOW=always` instead should do the trick.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks! I answered the question and tagged you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Adaephon

I removed the space and changed it to `SPACESHIP_BATTERY_SHOW=always`

[image]